# How to update product variations quantities

Tags: product-variations, etsy

I'm trying to update quantities for products and everything is fine for listing with one option. All I do is get Inventory, change quantities in offerings and send it back.

Problems starts when I'm trying to update multiple variations - then know I should include (if needed):

```
"price_on_property": [],
"quantity_on_property": [],
"sku_on_property": []
```

When I just copy array from results I got 403 error without any `X-Error-Detail`.

I was trying to make those properties like this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/etsy-api-v2/dViLQpgqZJY but ended up having

> "Expected int value for 'sku_on_property' (got 'string')" 400 error

I'm using this lib for oAuth https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

I'm sending those values as URL encoded build by `http_build_query` function, so it looks like

`&sku_on_property[0]=200&sku_on_property[1]=513&quantity_on_property[0]=200&quantity_on_property[1]=513`

My question is how this request should look like?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is like this:

```
&sku_on_property=200,513&quantity_on_property=200,513
```

This is how Etsy needs its requests.